# Change the widget after addWidget

Tags: python, pyqt

I have the following problem:

In the second script I want to change the `self.widget` to add WebViewEngine for browsering. I will do some more changes in the positioning of the widget. Because of that the second script dont know the exact position. In the moment it works with the expression `self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)`. But here i must know the exact position of the widget.

I only can add something at to the second script, because the the first one is generated with `uic.completeUiDir`.

I hope it is now more understandable.
Best regrads and thanks for the help.

```
#first script for creating the Ui
#   generated with: uic.compileUiDir("Example")
# if I change here something, it will be overwritten next time
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets,QtWebEngineWidgets
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
class Ui_Download_explorer(object):
    def setupUi(self, Download_explorer):
        Download_explorer.setObjectName("Download_explorer")
        Download_explorer.resize(400, 300)
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(Download_explorer)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Download_explorer)
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")

        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)


        self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(Download_explorer)
        self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")


        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.textBrowser, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.gridLayout_2.addLayout(self.gridLayout, 0, 0, 1, 1)

        self.retranslateUi(Download_explorer)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Download_explorer)

    def retranslateUi(self, Download_explorer):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Download_explorer.setWindowTitle(_translate("Download_explorer", "Form"))
    




#Second script for changing the window:

class Download_Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Download_Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.ui = Ui_Download_explorer()

        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.widget = (QtWebEngineWidgets.QWebEngineView())

        self.widget.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(
            self.on_downloadRequested
            )
        url = "https://google.com"
        self.widget.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))

            # noinspection PyTypeChecker
        self.widget.settings().setFontSize(0, 20)

        self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)

            # Downloadtext
        self.ui.textBrowser.setText("Hallo World")


    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QWebEngineDownloadItem*")
    def on_downloadRequested(self, download):
        old_path = download.url().path()  # download.path()
        suffix = QtCore.QFileInfo(old_path).suffix()
        path, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(
            self, "Save File", old_path, "*." + suffix
        )
        if path:
            download.setPath(path)
            download.accept()
            download.finished.connect(self.foo)

    @staticmethod
    def foo():
        print("finished")





window = Download_Widget()


window.showMaximized()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question is confusing

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and consider that by *reproducible* we also mean that we should understand the *logic* behind your code: for instance, you're talking about two scripts, but since you merged them we cannot really understand where (and **how**) the replacement of `self.widget` happens.

Comment: Add a `changeWidget(widget)` method to the ui class that knows where to put the new widget.

Comment: @ekhumoro Can you please explain what you mean. I am really new with python and programming at all. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Subw00feR A proper explanation would require seeing all of the relevant code (i.e. a [mcve]),

Comment: @ekhumoro Now it should be possible to start the programm.  My problem is update the widget, so that i havn't to place it again. Because now I create my Widget with calling class DownloadWidget -> in this class i create the said window with calling the class `Ui_Download_explorer(object):`  -> After this I change the properties of the widget in the class `Ui_Download_explorer(object):` ->  i only can see my changes when I placing the widget again with `self.ui.gridLayout.addWidget(self.widget, 0, 0, 1, 1)`. If I don't, I can't see the webbrowser. I hope the can understand me, I am trying hard.

Comment: @Subw00feR I don't really have much to add. Why can't you just create a method on `Ui_Download_explorer` that does whatever you want so you can call it from `Download_Widget`?

Comment: @ekhumoro Because `Ui_Download_explorer` is created by the "Qt Creator 4.14.2" and I really don't get how I can add in Qt Creator the QtWebEngine. So when I add code to `Ui_Download_explorerer ` it will be overwriten the next time.

Comment: @Subw00feR See [Using Qt Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) in the [PyQt Docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/index.html), and use the approach shown in the 2nd or 3rd example shown there.